# Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread ios 13.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

My app is running fine with all the devices but only crashes with iphone Xr and the crash report looks like the:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

file link https://drive.google.com/open?id=19lkVCSN9LuShROGXAErE_mNn6E-tO6up

Comment: Please share your project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The code on your main thread generated this `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)` exception. You should [symbolicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATION) this log so you can see precisely where it crashed. Until you do that, you’re just guessing what the source of the problem is. A symbolicated log will tend to narrow down the problem to a particular line of code, from which you can start your diagnosis.

Re `EXC_BREAKPOINT`, [Technical Note TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) says:

> Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>
> - a non-optional type with a nil value
> - a failed forced type conversion
>
> Look at the Backtraces to determine where the unexpected condition was encountered. Additional information may have also been logged to the device's console. You should modify the code at the crashing location to gracefully handle the runtime failure. For example, use Optional Binding instead of force unwrapping an optional.

For what it’s worth, there’s a very good chance that the problem is not related to the fact that the device was an iPhone X, but something else related to that user’s device, settings, permissions, or environment.